# Archive::Extract Module gives warnings in perl v5.12.3 on mac os x lion

Tags: perl, osx-lion, perl-module

I am using the default perl distribution(version 5.12.3) that came bundled with os x lion. When I use the module Archive::Extract in scripts with the -W module it gives the following warnings:

```
Subroutine version::declare redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 139.
Subroutine version::qv redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 140.
Subroutine version::vcmp redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 142.
Subroutine version::stringify redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 145.
Subroutine version::("" redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 146.
Subroutine version::new redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 147.
Subroutine version::parse redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 148.
Subroutine UNIVERSAL::VERSION redefined at /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/version.pm line 194.
Name "IPC::Cmd::I18N::en::Lexicon" used only once: possible typo at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/Locale/Maketext.p\
m line 444.
Name "Archive::Extract::I18N::en::Lexicon" used only once: possible typo at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/Locale/Ma\
ketext.pm line 444.
Name "Win32::Locale::Lexicon" used only once: possible typo at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/I18N/LangTags/Detect.pm l\
ine 140.
Name "Params::Check::I18N::en::Lexicon" used only once: possible typo at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/Locale/Maket\
ext.pm line 444.
Name "Module::Load::Conditional::I18N::en::Lexicon" used only once: possible typo at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3/\
Locale/Maketext.pm line 444.
```

I tried running upgrade in CPAN. I even deleted my .cpan directory and reconfigured my CPAN. I tested the module and it seems to work fine. But somehow I am uncomfortable with the warnings.

An other problem which made me post this question is some of my other modules are not being upgraded (via CPAN of course). This never happened to me when I was running linux.

```
Failed during this command:
 PMQS/BerkeleyDB-0.49.tar.gz                  : make NO
 MIKER/NetAddr-IP-4.058.tar.gz                : make_test NO
 DMR/DProf-19970614.tar.gz                    : make NO
 NWCLARK/perl-5.8.6.tar.gz                    : make NO isa perl
 JESSE/perl-5.13.9.tar.gz                     : make NO isa perl
 SHERZODR/Class-PObject-2.17.tar.gz           : make_test NO
 GBARR/IO-Tty-0.04.tar.gz                     : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 65280
 DOY/Moose-2.0004.tar.gz                      : make_test NO
 RJBS/perl-5.15.2.tar.bz2                     : make NO isa perl
 FLORA/perl-5.15.4.tar.gz                     : make NO isa perl
```

Should I try to clean up the default perl installation and use homebrew or macports to do a clean install? Is there something obvious I am missing which is causing all the problems?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

From [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)...

```
-W   Enables all warnings regardless of "no warnings" or $^W.
```

You got what you asked for.

You shouldn't be using `-W` in normal operation.  Sometimes modules deliberately turn off warnings for certain things, because they know what they're doing will trigger them.

Try `-w` instead.

As for your other question... sometimes CPAN modules fail to install.  A change of Perl version or operating system can do this.  You'll have to look at the verbose output of the install attempts.  Or you can `look Module::Name` to be dropped into a shell in the source tarball of Module::Name where you can test and debug manually.

That said, it's recommended to leave the operating system supplied Perl alone and install a fresh one for development.  This allows you to make whatever changes you want, install whatever modules you want and whatever version of Perl you want without risking messing up your operating system or having your upgrades blown over in the next OS upgrade.

[perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew) is one of the best ways to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try it with -w. It gives a fairly reasonable warning about Win32::Locale::Lexicon which I am willing to ignore. I will give perlbrew a shot.